# Get x y position of element relative to parent div Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given the following markup:

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='inner'>
    <div class='target'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And styles:

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 2000px;
}

.target {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
}
```

How would I go about scrolling the `.container` with `$('.container').scrollLeft(X)` and `$('.container').scrollTop(X)` to center `.target` in the middle of the viewport?

I get it to work by playing around with static values but as soon as the size of the screen changes, e.g. on mobile or tablets, then the centering is off.

I've also tried doing:

```
$('.container').scrollLeft($('.target').position().left);
$('.container').scrollTop($('.target').position().top);
```

But this doesn't seem to work, the centering is way off. I dont' know if this is because the `.target` is contained in a div with `overflow: scroll`.

Comment: You can center `.target` in the middle of viewport on in the middle of `.inner` with CSS. After that, you might want to scroll to that element.. is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly. I've added `position: relative;` to the `.inner` element and `absolute` to `.target` element and I calculated the position in jQuery based on the elements `width`'s and `height`'s. I hope this is what you need:

```js
var x = $('.inner').width() / 2 - $('.target').width() / 2
var y = $('.inner').height() / 2 - $('.target').height() / 2;

$('.container').scrollLeft(x);
$('.container').scrollTop(y);

$('.target').css({
  left: x,
  top: y
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
.inner {
  width: 3000px;
  height: 2000px;
  position: relative;
}
.target {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='inner'>
    <div class='target'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```